# Opera mini v12 automatic clear cache history & cookies

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, browser, cache, opera-mini

Is there a way to get rid of all cache, history and cookies automatically.
Preferably each time I shut down or start up the browser Opera mini.

If this one doesn't anyone know another browser that does?

Manually deleting each privacy setting all the time is a pain in the ass.

And if no mobile browser supports this is there another way to get rid of
all this data automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you try two avenues:

- [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) (Which does prompt for to clear cache, etc on exit), there's the Mini version, this version as linked to the Play Store, and the HD version.
- [History Eraser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.eraser) - this clears all the history of SMS, Calls, Browser history etc in one swell foop.

Comment: about this History Eraser.... seriously... i wonder why ppl would install if you checkout what this "so-called-app" permissions wants to have: edit and read my SMS or MMS, My personal information ( read browser history and bookmarks ), Full internet access (why the hell for?)... seriously??

Comment: That's what it does, barring internet access (can block  it with firewall) it does wipe sms, mms, call logs etc..

Answer (score 0):

The PC / desktop Opera version has that feature. Unfortunately, it's not available in mobile versions.

You can try the following browsers instead:

**Dolphin**

- `Settings > Exit Settings > Clear Cache When Exiting`
- `Settings > Exit Settings > Clear History When Exiting`
- `Settings > Exit Settings > Clear Cookies When Exiting`

**UC Browser**

- `Settings > Clear Data > Clear data on exit`
- `Settings > Clear Data > Cookies`
- `Settings > Clear Data > Form`
- `Settings > Clear Data > History`
- `Settings > Clear Data > Cache`

*As of this time, I prefer to use UC Browser, because Dolphin is giving me a lot of issues on my Samsung Galaxy S2, running CM10.1.*

Comment: Dolphin i tried and looks surprisingly nice if it has a no-script add-on or option that its better than chrome or firefox. No-script is a firefox addon that blocks all JavaScript except for the domain you manually allow.